# GLMNET causes error - Unrecognised Statement, did you Forget to add \FIXED_FORMAT?

Tags: r, fortran, glmnet

I am working in R with the glmnet package. It's a package where i can do ridge & lasso regressions. In this R package the code is connected with a fortran code, that's where the whole calculating stuff happens.
My goal is to change something in this code and then i try to connect the new fortran code with the r package (that's the plan).

Now my Problem:

I found the fortran code glmnet5.f90, so i conclude that this code is a free format file. When i run this code i get fthe following error:

```
error 399 - Unrecognised Statement, did you Forget to add \FIXED_FORMAT?
```

In the Internet i found something like to copy the code in a fixed format file but i only get more errors.

Another thing i noticed was that comments are written with "C" in the first column, but fortran 90 uses "!" for comments, so maybe it's a fortran 77 code but I don't know. The Compiler is for 90/95 so this shouldnt be a problem right?

Right now i am using the FTN95 compiler of silverfrost. The code has over 7000 lines that's why i will give you the link to the code.
[CRAN-package-glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html)
You find the code in glmnet\src\glmnet5.f90.

Comment: Please make a more concise question with a short clear problem statement and some code example. Copy the lines that cause the errors here. And **please** try to write normal English. Use capital I. Do not use shortcuts like idk or sth. I really could not correct everything, it is too much, but it is a pain to read.

Comment: Try to be clear. Tell us which compiler and version, bot that it is Fortran 90. Did you read the error message? Did you try to use the `\FIXED_FORMAT` flag? It is likely to help. The compiler is suggesting it to you for a reason. It is much faster to just try what compiler tells you than to write a lengthy story on StackOverflow.

Comment: @VladimirF i use Plato version 4.75. Thank you for correcting me. Maybe you can tell me how to use a flag and yes i read the error message but i still dont know what to do. That is why i can't copy the lines that cause the error. becuase i have no idea where i can find this error.